# Redirecting URL to access web server with NGINX in WSL does not work

Tags: networking, webserver, nginx, windows-subsystem-for-linux, redirection

We have a C# .Net Core 3.1 application that hosts a web site (all configured in Program.cs and Startup.cs) which works wonderfully on Windows. It is setup so the welcome page is shown on https://ip/ProductName instead of directly https://ip/. Unfortunately, we can't seem to setup it up the same way using the kestrel .Net Core code, and have set it up to listen on http://localhost:5000/.

My solution to this problem was to set up NGINX to redirect all requests from HTTP to HTTPS, and redirect requests from location /ProductName to 127.0.0.1:5000. This works well on the production appliance this program runs on, but I can't seem to make it work on Windows Subsystem for Linux (so that developers wouldn't need a physical appliance to debug/test stuff).

Here is the nginx.conf that we use both in our production appliance and that I am trying to use for WSL:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 1;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {

    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    # Redirect All HTTP to HTTPS
    server {
        listen       8080 default_server;
        server_name  _;

        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    # HTTPS server
    #
    server {
        listen       8443 ssl;
        server_name  localhost;

        ssl_certificate      /path/to/my/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /path/to/my/server.key;

    ssl_protocols  TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        root /path/to/my/wwwroot;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5001;

        }

        location /ProductName/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that we are not including any files in either `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` or `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`, nor has the `/etc/nginx/modules-enabled/` have any other conf files present.

One of the key differences between this file (for WSL) and the production one, is that we are using port 8080 and 8443 instead of 80 and 443, since I keep getting an permission denied error when it tries to bind on port 80, even if I start the NGINX service with sudo.

When I start the NGINX service with this file, I cannot access my webpage using http://127.0.0.1/ProductName (which I would assume would work since it should be redirected to HTTPS and then following my second rule be redirected to http://127.0.0.1:5000/ which my program is listening on), nor using https://127.0.0.1/ProductName. I can **only** access it via http://127.0.0.1:5000/, as if the NGINX service wasn't running at all.

I have tried googling how to setup NGINX on WSL, and have found some people saying that it should work as is, without any other additional tricks or configuration needed compared to a "real" Linux setup.

What am I missing here for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

> What am I missing here for this to work?

The change from 80 and 443 to 8080 and 8443 may be the culprit here.

Using `http://127.0.0.1/ProductName` and `https://127.0.0.1/ProductName` are generally equivalent to using `http://127.0.0.1:80/ProductName` and `https://127.0.0.1:443/ProductName` respectively (that is, ex. browsers assume the use of these standard ports so that people don't have to specify them for every web request).

Try using `http://127.0.0.1:8080/ProductName` and `https://127.0.0.1:8443/ProductName` and see if those work. If they do, then you will likely need to resolve your port conflict or come up with another solution which is acceptable to you.